# SetOptions in parallel computation

Tags: numerical-integration, parallelization, options

I have `NIntegrate[]` inside a `ParallelDo[]` loop. Outside the loop I set some options for the integration using `SetOptions[]`.

To give an example:

```
SetOptions[NIntegrate, MaxRecursion -> 20];
ParallelDo[NIntegrate[Cos[20000 x]/Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1, 4}]
```

results in the error output

```
NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {0.}. NIntegrate obtained 0.005799163549191785` and 0.014875547652988553` for the integral and error estimates.
```

Thus, not every kernel seems to know about the set options. How to distribute this setting over every kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ParallelEvaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelEvaluate.html) to make sure that `SetOptions` is evaluated by each kernel:

```
ParallelEvaluate[SetOptions[NIntegrate, MaxRecursion -> 20]];
ParallelDo[NIntegrate[Cos[20000 x]/Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 1}], {i, 1, 4}]
(* no messages *)
```